# How can I match all images without thumb image using regexp

Tags: regex, filenames, string-matching

How can I match all images without thumb image using regexp ?

```
hi.gif
thumb.gif
hello.gif
```

Result should be :

```
hi.gif
hello.gif
```

I am using `.+(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG)` to match all images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -ve lookahead assertion as:

```
^(?!thumb).+\.(?:gif|GIF|jpg|JPG)$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/txyN2d68he)

[**Regexr link**](http://regexr.com?2slkv)

Comment: @faressoft, since you are testing multiple inputs, you need to enable multi-line mode. See the link in my post.

Comment: It is very good. but how can I match only ".gif" when image != thumb.gif

Comment: If the image is not `thumb`, you want to capture only the `.` and the extension? If yes, just change the non-capturing parenthesis `(?:  )` to `(  )`

Comment: Yes. If you want to capture the `.` aswell, put that in the grouping: http://www.rubular.com/r/CUtsdxSwCh

Comment: I want match .gif for the first image and third image without its name

Comment: result shoud be .gif and .gif not hi.gif and hello.gif

Comment: Check the `Match captures:` section.

Answer (score 0):

Put a negative look-ahead at the start:

```
(?!thumb\.).+(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex:

```
.+(?<!^thumb)\..+$
```

Also add options Multiline.